# My MacBook Pro (13" Mid 2012) keeps crashing with a blue screen and I got a panic report

Tags: macbook-pro

So for the past few weeks, my macbook pro (13-inch, Mid 2012, 2.9Ghz intel core i7, 8GB 1600MHz DDR3, intel HD graphics 4000 1024MB, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5) seems to crash randomly with a rapid blue screen and then restarts as if normal. The last time it did this (about ten minutes ago), it produced a panic report as follows. I took it to the apple store today. They plugged in an Ethernet cable and said the hardware was fine within 1 minute. They looked at the panic report and said that the panic report says it is a CPU issue and I might have to replace the logic board. On the other hand, it could be a software issue and I could try updating to el Capitan with a fresh install. So basically they said it's either a software or hardware problem but they can't be sure: what do I do??

Thank you for any help that you can give me. My panic report is below at this link (couldn't get any answers on the apple forum)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7574180

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try updating to el Capitan with a fresh install like the suggested, I guess!

Comment: Do what any sensible person would do. 1. Update to the newest software. If that works, count your blessings; if not, gotta replace the logic board. Can't do anything but test after each change and hope it fixes the issue.